# GDAL NULL Path Value On Production Server

Tags: gdal, c#, visual-studio

I am using c# and visual studio.

I have an app using GDAL that works perfectly on the Dev Server. When I transfer it to Production the app fails. I receive the following error message:

```
An error occurred while warping the file: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path 1

   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)

   at GDAL.Services.GDALService.Warp(String fileName, String destinationFileName, String& errorMessage, STring s_SRS, String t_SRS)

at Create.Manager.GDALManager.Convert(ImageFile imageFile, String& errorMessage)
```

GDALManager Code referenced:

```
try
{
    if (imageFile.CoordSys == CoordSys.UTM)
    {
        warpResult = GDAL.Services.GDALService.Warp(source, tempImageFileName, out fnErrorMessage, null, "NAD83");
    }
    else
    {
        warpResult = GDAL.Services.GDALService.Warp(source, tempImageFileName, out fnErrorMessage, imageFile.CoordSys.Name, "NAD83");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    fnErrorMessage = "An error occurred while warping the file: " + ex.ToString();
}
```

Source and Destination Path: "\\DataServer\Images\Raster\Raster_Seamless"

All source and destination file paths are the same for both Dev and Production.

Comment: How are you setting `tempImageFileName`?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I am creating a local folder using  tempImageFileName = tempDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source) + ".tif";

Comment: Did you check if source is null?

Comment: I have checked on the dev server but visual studio is not loaded onto the prod server.

Comment: Did you try changing your code so that it checks to make sure that 1) source is not null or whitespace, 2) source directory exists (i.e. network folder is mapped) 3) source directory can be written to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

The reason for the null is that when I transferred the app to production, I did not transfer gdal components the app was referencing from other apps. Instead of throwing an error that the files could not be found, the app just listed the null path. It was very misleading since when I installed VS on the prod server and debugged, all paths and data were shown. The app just didn't know what to do with the information since it did not have the other gdal references.

I figured it out when looking at the log file and reading the error file source paths.